# R Mapreduce library 'rmr2' shows a warning message when loaded

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce, rhadoop

**Why is the R Mapreduce library 'rmr2' generating a warning message ?**

I have installed 'rmr2' library to execute Mapreduce programs in R. But when

```
library(rmr2)
```

is specified in R, it generates the following warning message:

```
Please review your hadoop settings. See help(hadoop.settings)
Warning message:
S3 methods ‘gorder.default’, ‘gorder.factor’, ‘gorder.data.frame’,  ‘gorder.matrix’, ‘gorder.raw’ 
were declared in NAMESPACE but not found
```

What could be the reason ?

Comment: I am not sure and I wrote the thing. `gorder` is a generic used in test only, so no worries about this, but yes, I'd love to make that go away too. Pull requests welcome.

Comment: @piccolbo: So the 'gorder' messages won't affect the program execution in any way right ?

Comment: Well, "the program" is a little vague, but no, in general this should be of no consequence. gorder is only used in the tests and the tests pass.

Comment: Thanks piccolbo for the help  :)

Answer (score 3):

The main reason, you didn't include the path. before run library(rmr2), you must include the given 4 paths to prevent these type warnings.

Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME="/home/hadoop/hadoop-1.1.2") //Its hadooop path

Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="/home/hadoop/hadoop-1.1.2/bin/hadoop") //It's CMD path

Sys.setenv(HADOOP_STREAMING="/home/hadoop/work/hadoop-1.1.2/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.1.2.jar") //It's streaming path

Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64") //Java path it is.

Than you include library(rmr2) and library(rhdfs) to do further process. All the best.

Comment: Mentioned all the 4 paths. It still gives the warning message.

Comment: Here pls hange hadoop name by your system's username it means /home/your-system-username/... and other also. check java path and streaming path properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't write the paths as it should be:

HADOOP_CMD='/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/hadoop'
HADOOP_STREAMING='/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.2.jar'
HADOOP_HOME='/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2'

the '' are very important, check if you forgot them.